# Random Forest algorithm in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, random-forest

I have exported a trained model using Weka, the dataset used contains 3 columns:

- Number of deleted files (Number).
- Path (Deleted file path).
- Severity (3 levels: Critical, Normal, Suspicious).

After exporting the model, I want to take an input using WatchService API in Java to monitor deleted files on a specific directory and get Random Forest classification using the exported model. Any guidance ? I tried to search many websites and found minimal related info.

Answer (score 0):

The Weka manual PDF that comes with your Weka installation contains a chapter on how to use the API. From the 3.9.5 manual:

- 18.12 Serialization (how to save/load a model)
- 18.7.3 Classifying Instances (how to make predictions, using a file as input)
- 18.3 Creating datasets in memory (for generating data on the fly)

Some of this information is available from the Weka wiki:

- [Use weka in your java code](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/)
- [Creating arff file](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/) (shows how to create datasets in memory and then save to disk)
- [API articles](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/using_the_api/)

Your Weka distribution also comes with example classes (wekaexamples.zip). The wiki links to the repository containing them:
https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/weka_examples/